# modules of different CPU types were found

Tags: visual-studio, dll, x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I am just using some dlls in my program, they are listed as:

OPENCV_CORE242D.DLL

OPENCV_IMPROC242D.DLL

VL.DLL

and they all ask for a dll called "MSVCP90D.dll", which I have downloaded and put it into 2 directories: C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (because I am using a 64-bit machine), as guided.

Now I am using a small gadget called "Dependency Walker" and checked the dependency, it says something like this:
[image: Caputure of Dependency Walker]

Comment: This link might explain some of the red lines: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/393036

Answer (score 2):

Version 2.2.6000 of Dependency Walker does not have this issue.  Get your update at http://dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Best answer by far. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but also make sure you're using the right version (x86/x64) of dependency walker.