# rJava and java web app integration error

Tags: java, r, rjava

Trying to call R from Java Program and we see the following error:

```
Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\Apps\Analytics\statistics\R\sdk\library\rJava
\jri\x64\jri.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.<clinit>(Rengine.java:19)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29608639/482745) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244483/482745) answer helped me to solve same issue.

I used newer tool [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) and found that R.dll and jvm.dll was not found.

So I added R.dll to the path as is written in [JRI FAQ](https://www.rforge.net/JRI/)