# Qt Deployment error 0xc0000007b on Windows

Tags: qt

I have a Qt 5.12 Windows app. I'm using Qt Creator and Mingw 64 bit.
I've deployed the app by windeployqt.exe. When I start it, the app requires the libgcc_s_seh-1.dll file. After I paste it in the dir, I get the 0xc000007b error. I ran Dependency Walker and it gives me the following errors:

```
Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Error: A circular dependency was detected.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

This is my .pro file

```
QT += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Control
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libgcc


##CONFIG += c++11
##QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in the past, but I am not pretty sure if it's the same reason because I was compiling with MVSC.

In my case, the application internally links with x86 dependency files. I did [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms246588(v=vs.100)) and install x64 dependency files and link with x64 files.

Anyway, the old version of Dependency Walker doesn't know to skip 32-bit DLLs in PATH when processing a 64-bit EXE or DLL the way Windows does, so some errors are not really relevant. You may find more information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639816/modules-of-different-cpu-types-were-found).

If the problem remains, try to avoid the usage of a static version of libgcc, acording to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304531/compiling-with-static-libgcc-static-libstdc-still-results-in-dynamic-depende). It is not designed to be statically linked.

```
...
#QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libgcc
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got that error when the compiled app could not see the `Qt` `dll`s, so check your *path*. It could also be that it cannot find other `gcc` `dll`, like `libwinpthread-1.dll`.